# add 2 button when I'm clicking xamarin

Tags: c#, android, button, xamarin

I am trying to make a button that adds 2 to a number in a textbox every time I touch it.
I know how to add 1 like :

```
int l; 
t1.Text = l++.Tostring();
```

How can I add 2 when the button is touched?

Comment: What do you mean by "add 2 button"?

Comment: Like I press the button and it add 2 to textbox

Comment: parse the textboxes text as an integer, add 2 to it, and set it back to a string

Comment: But it add 1 to my textbox

Answer (score 1):

By "add 2 to textbox" i assume you mean:

```
int l = 0;
t1.Text = (l + 2).ToString();
```

**Edit:**

To make things clear - this will always set your `TextBox` to 2.
If you want to increment `l` each time the button is clicked, you have to make `l` a class level variable:

```
public class SomeActivity()
{
   private int l = 0;

   private void OnButtonClicked()
   {
      l += 2
      t1.Text = l.ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `t1.Text = "2";` (I assume `l` is scoped to a method)

Comment: I'm not sure how he's using this code. I assume he wants to know how to add a constant to an integer.

Comment: Also being pedantic, this won't compile as `l` not initialized. btw I agree to @Sayse

Comment: im tried it but it giveing me this error https://www.dropbox.com/s/hj45h6lwq3ua1ff/error11.PNG

Comment: that what i want: when im clicking on the button it will show the number 2 and when im clicking again it will be 4 and then 6....

Comment: @kipo See my edited answer. As said above, you have to initialize your `int l` with an initial value

Comment: Its still equivalent to `"2"`

Comment: do i have to do private int or just int is ok?

Comment: if you only declared `int l` it is equivalent to `private int l`

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is the following:

```
int l;
if (Int32.TryParse(t1.Text, out l))
{
   t1.Text = (l+2).ToString();
}
```

This is a very basic question and it might cause some anger to post such questions. Therefore I would encourage you to read a book or tutorial on C# before posting similar questions.
Unfortunately I only know german books, but a search on Google should help you out.

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect, basic questions are fine as long as they are clear, show research effort, and an attempt to solve the problem

Comment: that what i want: when im clicking on the button it will show the number 2 and when im clicking again it will be 4 and then 6

Comment: @kipo - This does exactly that

Comment: and what you are giveing is when i click it put 2 and another two and when i click two times it gives 22 and not 4

Comment: int l;
                int b = 2;
                if (Int32.TryParse(t1.Text, out l))
                {
                    t1.Text = (l + b).ToString();
                }

Comment: Sorry, i forgot a parenthesis there.

Answer (score 0):

int count = 0;

buttonObject.Click += (sender, args) =>
             {

```
            count += 2;
            buttonObject.Text = count.ToString();
        };
```